# Tax exemption in Tokyo

Tags: tokyo, tax-refunds

I'm from India and I visited Tokyo recently. This was my first foreign trip. At Haneda International Airport I bought a few items and tax was exempted for foreign buyers when I showed my passport but they attached the bill and a slip in my passport.

What should I do with that bill now? Can I remove it or should it be in my passport forever? I thought when I reach India, Customs people would check and remove it but there was no customs check.

So, what do I do with it now?

Answer (score 35):

In principle, you are supposed to visit the Japanese customs office in the departure area of the airport before leaving (there is no systematic customs check for departing passengers in Japan), and they will just collect the receipts. There is currently no penalty for not doing so, however, so if you have already left, you can just throw them away.

Comment: If I remove it, a small red mark will be left on my passport page. Is that ok?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is the correct answer.  (And no, nobody ever goes to the customs office.)

Comment: Last time I departed Tokyo there was an unattended box in the terminal for you to put your receipts in.

Answer (score 21):

You can remove it and throw it away. It is for use when leaving Japan, in case Japanese Customs want to check the goods against the receipt. They rarely, if ever, do.

Comment: If I remove it, a small red mark will be left on my passport page. Is that ok?

Comment: Doesn't matter. 